# How to pass values down through nested WebUserControls?

Tags: c#, .net, webusercontrol

I'm trying to pass a value to a WebUserControl, and then onwards to a second nested WebUsercontrol. The first Control can get the value without any problems, and in debug mode it seems like the value is indeed passed on to the nested control aswell, but it somehow gets lost before rendering the page.

In the example I'm trying to pass the "headerTheme"-value.

Embedding the top-level-WebUserControl:

```
<uuc:FrameWork 
        runat="server" 
        ID="FrameWork" 
        EnableViewState="true"
        headerTheme="myValue"
         />
```

top-level-WebUserControl ascx:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server">
<!-- Header control Start -->   

    <uuc:HeaderControl runat="server" ID="HeaderControl" EnableViewState="true"/>

<!--  Header control End -->
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

top-level-WebUserControl codebehind:

```
public string headerTheme { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlaceHolder head = (PlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("HeaderPlaceHolder");


            HeaderControl.headerTheme = headerTheme;
            head.Controls.Add(Header);               
        }
```

Nested WebUserControl codebehind:

```
public string headerTheme { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            msg.Text = "Value: " + headerTheme;
        }
```

Nested WebUserControl ascx:

```
<asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Also the nested usercontrol is inside a placeholder, which gets placed in a second placeholder on the masterpage. Since there are actually multiple nested controls in the top-level WebUserControl, this is to place the header, footer, menu and so on correctly on the masterpage.

The result is a null-value in the end, and the value set in the beginning gets lost somewhere along the way. I can't seem to find out where or how.

If anybody has a better way of passing down a value to the nested WebUserControls that would be great too :)

Comment: Why not store this value in your ViewState which is available to all your controls for the current request regardless of hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing the issue. The Page_Load event in the nested WebUserControl was fired twice. This happended when adding the placeholder-control wich contained the WebUserControl to a placeholder on the Masterpage.

The answer was to add the value: HeaderControl.headerTheme = headerTheme;

after adding the placeholder-control: head.Controls.Add(Header);

(Header is a placeholder that contains HeaderControl)

/Magne